# How to avoid brace conflict in postman?

Tags: postman

I have occur a problem when using postman. In postman, the brace {} means to use environment variable. But I post something like https://www.google.com/{xxxxx}, now the brace need to be used in url, not for environment variable. So how can I avoid this conflict?

Comment: you mean the brace is part of the data being sent?

Comment: yes. It is conflict.

Answer (score 1):

`{` and `}` are reserved characters and can't be used in the path of a URL (see [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3)). They should be url-encoded, and this is what some http libraries do silently.

You should replace `{` by `%7B` and `}` by `%7D`, so your URL would look like: `https://www.google.com/%7Bxxxxx%7D`

If you want more information about the encoding of ASCII characters, you can find a simple table [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp).